# Merge is giving NA data in the added columns even though all=T

Tags: r, merge

Solved: there was an issue with capital letters between the two df's

I am trying to merge two df's so that they are vertically added to each other based on a common variable. However when I do merge, all data is removed from the df that is added.

I have tried the all=T in the code like below, which is ran with the dput at the end of the post. I am using a small dput as I can't share much more of my work.

`combined <- merged(df1, df2, by="scientific_name", all=T)`

The goal is to merge both data frames, which originally have an uneven number of rows. It should be merged on the variable "scientific_name". However when I run "merge", the data from df2 turns into NA's only.

When running the dput and supplied code from merging I get that all variables from column Hand.Wing.Index (prveciously df2) contains NA values. The goal I want to achieve is merging these two data frames on the variable `scientific_name` without the data loss in what previously was df2.

`dput df1`

```
df1 <- structure(list(scientific_name = c("branta canadesis", "alopochen aegyptiaca", 
"anas platyrhychos", "cygnus olor", "buteo buteo"), common_name = c("canadian goose", 
"egyptian goose", "mallard", "mute swan", "common buzzard"), 
    geographic_area = c("western europe", "western europe", "western europe", 
    "western europe", "western europe"), n_sampled = c(1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 5L)), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

`dput df2`

```
df2 <- structure(list(scientific_name = c("Accipiter albogularis", "Accipiter badius", 
"Accipiter bicolor", "Accipiter brachyurus", "Accipiter brevipes"
), Hand.Wing.Index = c(33.9, 32.9, 24.6, 31.7, 40.2), Habitat = c("Forest", 
"Shrubland", "Woodland", "Forest", "Forest"), Habitat.Density = c(1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), Trophic.Level = c("Carnivore", "Carnivore", 
"Carnivore", "Carnivore", "Carnivore"), Trophic.Niche = c("Vertivore", 
"Vertivore", "Vertivore", "Vertivore", "Vertivore"), Primary.Lifestyle = c("Insessorial", 
"Insessorial", "Generalist", "Insessorial", "Generalist"), Migration = c(2L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 3L)), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to specifically and clearly define the problem that you are trying to solve. Additional details — including all relevant code, error messages, and debugging logs — will help readers to better understand your problem and [what you are asking]. Please also add reproducible code for the data.frames.

Comment: Please can you provide (small) data frames for `df1` and `df2` that illustrate the problem. Also specify what you were expecting to see in the results. Thanks!

Comment: @datawookie I have added a dput which creates the merged data frame including the problems that arise. The goal is to not have NA data from the column hand.wing.index on

Comment: Thanks for updating your question to include data, but we would need  the `dput` from both `df1` and `df2`, *not* from `combined`

Comment: @jpsmith dput for df1 and df2 has been added

Comment: Did you mean `merge()` rather than `merged()`?

Comment: Also, just looking at the data in the `scientific_name` column of those two data frames, I'm not sure that you will actually get a decent merge/join because in `df1` they are lowercase and in `df2` they are capitalised.

Comment: For the data that you have provided can you please specify: (1) how many columns you expect to see in the results (are you only expecting to find the columns which are common to `df1` and `df2`?) and (2) how many rows you expect to see in the result (if the answer is 10 then something like `rbind()` should do the job along with column selection).

Comment: @datawookie df1 originally has 514 rows, df2 originally has 11009 rows as it's an overview based on species. After a successful merge I will decrease the rows to 514 as well by removing anything with an NA in the variable geographic_area

Comment: Okay, so just to be clear, you are wanting the 514 rows from `df1` and the corresponding 514 rows from `df2`, matching on the `scientific_name` column? Cool. Please see my answer below. You need to make sure that the case in the `scientific_name` column is consistent otherwise you won't get any matches.

Comment: @datawookie Hi thanks for the answer! I also just realised that  the issue was a difference in the use of capital letters between the two datasets. Makes you feel silly for sure for missing that before. Thanks again for all the help though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a match between the `scientific_name` columns in the two data frames you need to ensure that they have consistent case (otherwise there won't be any matches).

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

merge(
  df1,
  df2 %>% mutate(scientific_name = str_to_lower(scientific_name)),
  by = "scientific_name",
  all = TRUE
)
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, your question could benefit from making it a bit clearer what is meant and/or by providing a reproducible example.

On topic; would simply using cbind() perhaps solve your issue?
For example:

```
set.seed(1)
df1 <- matrix(rnorm(20), 10, 2)
df2 <- matrix(rnorm(20), 10, 2)
df_new <- cbind(df1, df2)
```

**Update:**
I think it is becoming a bit clearer what you meant, and why cbind() might not work for your case.

In the following example I used merge(); but it only gives output for the cases where scientific_name is identical between the two data frames.

```
df1 <- structure(list(scientific_name = c("branta canadesis", "alopochen aegyptiaca", 
                                      "anas platyrhychos", "cygnus olor", "buteo buteo"), common_name = c("canadian goose", 
                                                                                                          "egyptian goose", "mallard", "mute swan", "common buzzard"), 
                  geographic_area = c("western europe", "western europe", "western europe", 
                                      "western europe", "western europe"), n_sampled = c(1L, 2L, 
                                                                                         1L, 1L, 5L)), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")

df2 <- structure(list(scientific_name = c("Accipiter albogularis", "Accipiter badius", 
                                      "Accipiter bicolor", "cygnus olor", "buteo buteo"
), Hand.Wing.Index = c(33.9, 32.9, 24.6, 31.7, 40.2), Habitat = c("Forest", 
                                                              "Shrubland", "Woodland", "Forest", "Forest"), Habitat.Density = c(1L, 
                                                                                                                                2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), Trophic.Level = c("Carnivore", "Carnivore", 
                                                                                                                                                                   "Carnivore", "Carnivore", "Carnivore"), Trophic.Niche = c("Vertivore", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                     "Vertivore", "Vertivore", "Vertivore", "Vertivore"), Primary.Lifestyle = c("Insessorial", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "Insessorial", "Generalist", "Insessorial", "Generalist"), Migration = c(2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L)), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")

merge(df1, df2, by = 'scientific_name')
```

Comment: I just tested this with the data you provided and using cbind() seems to provide me with the required output (i.e., no NA's).

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment. Cbind doesn't seem to do the trick as the total number of columns do not match in the original data. I sadly can't share the full original data frame, so you couldn't have foreseen, thanks again for trying though. I'll try specifying the question more.

Comment: I think a differing number of columns should not be a problem using cbind(). Do you perhaps mean a differing number of rows between the df's?

Comment: Sorry yes, rows I meant! Been a long day

Comment: Hi, I feel like an idiot. I know why merge was not working as yours produced a workable example for Sitta europea. Turns out df2 had capitol letters for the genus name, which I didn't apply on purpose....

Comment: @Hartje; no problem! Glad that the issue is cleared up and is hopefully working as intended.